# Selected meshes vanish when in object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

So, I’m a total noob at Blender, just started learning it last week by using the Blender Guru’s Donut tutorial. During the process I found a problem with my Solidify Modifiers that I managed to fix (a problem with the normals I believe) but in the process I might have broken something. I’ll explain what happens with a New file (I tried reinstalling Blender 2.81, reseting settings and such and it didn’t work) cause it now happens everytime.

When I open a new file I find this:

[image]

Aparently nothing, right? But as you may notice, there is in fact a default cube.

When I change from Object to Edit Mode, I can see that it is selected and it looks normal.

And when I deselect it and go back to Object mode it’s back to normal. This also happens with individual selected faces so I guess the problem is with my selections? Also, this only happens in Solid Mode cause in Render Mode it looks as it’s suppose to be.

Does someone knows what may be causing this? I can’t find anything on the subject (Sorry if there is, I just couldn’t find it).

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Could you save the default file, and upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Then just paste the given code

Comment: Sorry it took me so long I didn't have access to my computer XD
I can't upload the file for some reason T_T
Does uploading it to my dropbox works?

Comment: Sure, as long as its public. Would you mind also posting your system specs?

Comment: I'll send my Drive instead XD
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mTeDNy9zCKAOb0u9NyJXHCS2L02gsXn0

Windows 10 Pro 64bits
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K @ 3.50GHz, 3501 Mhz. 4 Core(s), 8 Processor(s)
RAM 4GB

Comment: Hm, nope the cube shows up on my screen, not quite sure what the cause is. Can you add new objects like normal?

Comment: Yeah, I can add new objects normally. This bug doesn't stop me from doing things but it's really inconvenient having to unselect everything to see it in Object Mode :/
Maybe if I install an older version and then update it to the new one? I'll try that

Comment: Instead of going through that hassle,, delete the default cube then go to *File* > *Default File* > *Save as Default*. That will remove the buggy cube from your startup file. You'll only have to do that once so it's not too bad of a workaround

Comment: It didn't help cause every mesh I add and it's selected have that bug. And aparently the problem is in version 2.81 cause 2.80 is fine

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely a glitch, because the only other instance I know of something like  this happening is when a cube I added in POV-ray rendering disappeared in edit mode because a certain script wasn't installed. Try re-opening Blender, and if that doesn't work, then you may have to uninstall Blender then re-install it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both already and It didn't work T_T

Comment: This is not usual. It is not Blender then, that has the glitch. Check your graphics card.

Comment: My computer doesn't have a GPU :/
But it was working fine when I first installed it